# Labview 13 - Waveform graph not accepting all data

Tags: graph, charts, labview, waveform

I am having trouble being able to plot three different sets of data onto a waveform graph.  The waveform chart has no problem in accepting all the three sets of data, and displaying.  However i need a history of data that i can export to an excel document and examine.

The circuit is setup as follows:

An NI DAQ 6001 takes a temperature reading from an LM35 that is measuring a brass block.  Separate circuitry drives a current through a peltier device to maintain a specific temperature on this brass block.  It is fundamentally controlled by PID control to allow an operator to choice a temperature that the brass block can be set at.  To be able to tune the system perfectly i need to make a set of step changes and record the data and be able to graph at a later data to determine such characteristics as: linear / non-linearity / Oscillation / stability.

Unfortunately i do not know how to upload my program but i have attached a screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0hbg.png)

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlUTk.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using direct 1D array wired to the waveform graph.  You should build all waveforms using *Build Array* function to form a 2D array which will eventually display as different plots.

A proper way in displaying waveform in graph includes time component.  You would need to build waveform (Block Diagram --> Function Pallette --> Programming --> Waveform --> Build Waveform) with start time, delta Time for each 1D array.  Then you can bundle this waveform into a 1D array to plot multiple plots.

Sharing your VI can help solving quickly.  Just select all of your block diagram using Ctra+A and save it as VI snippet using *Edit-->Create VI Snippet from Selection*, then attach that image generated in this stack overflow response.